# Is it possible to scan and match a pattern using regex in redis?

Tags: redis

Say that I want to scan a set in redis using the SCAN function. Is it possible to pass a regex to MATCH with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `MATCH` is a pattern with wildcard support only.

Answer (score 2):

`MATCH` does not support regexes, only wildcards. However, you do have possibility of using Lua patterns in Lua scripts for redis.
[Lua patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) would be as powerful as POSIX regex patterns for most common practical usecases. Here is a gist which does the same by very helpful @itamarhaber

https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/19c8393f465b62c9cfa8

NOTE: This is NOT PRODUCTION FRIENDLY as it is resource intensive and does full scans.

Answer (score 0):

Just mention one small thing, since regex is not supportted, we can implement some of the matches by ourselves.

For example(with python):

```
def generator():
    target_pattern = 'user_\d+'
    simple_pattern = 'user_*'
    import re
    cursor, i = 0, 0
    while True:
        cursor, keys = rs.scan(cursor, match=simple_pattern, count=1000)
        for key in keys:
            if re.match(target_pattern, key):
                yield (i, key)
                i += 1
        if not keys:
            break

for cursor, keys in generator():
    print(cursor, keys)
    do_something()

# or 
def while_true_loop():
    target_pattern = 'user_\d+'
    simple_pattern = 'user_*'
    import re
    cursor = 0
    while True:
        cursor, keys = rs.scan(cursor, match=simple_pattern, count=1000)
        for key in keys:
            if re.match(target_pattern, key):
                do_something()
        if not keys:
            break
```