# How do I get ES module parent in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, module

I need to get the parent URL, path or specifier of a given ES module in Node.

I'm using `node --experimental-modules` / vanilla ES modules (no transpilation here!).

Currently the codebase is running on top of Node 10.5.

For example:

```
// moduleA.mjs
import { x } from './moduleB.mjs'
```

---

```
// moduleB.mjs

// How do I get the file URL, path or 
// the specifier of `moduleA`?
export const x = 11
```

Comment: What if `moduleB` is imported by multiple modules? It seems like basic behavior on the path of the parent would be super likely to make your code harder to manage.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this is possible.

Comment: What is "the" parent? One module can be a dependency in a million files. You, as developer, already know your import hierarchy, so this question strongly suggests that you're trying to solve a problem for which you *think* you need to know the parent, when what we really should be doing is talking about the problem you're trying to solve, instead. So: what are you doing that makes you think this is necessary?

Comment: there is a `module.parent`, (see [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_parent)) although it might not be exactly what you're looking for. It's "The module that first required this one."

Comment: @loganfsmyth Loader hooks provide the `parentModuleURL` which is the module that's being loading a dependency. I was looking for something like this.

Comment: @Pointy If this isn't currently possible, I may accept an answer that says "This isn't currently possible"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans As I've already commented, loader hooks provide the `parentModuleURL`, which is the one that being loaded a dependency.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In the other hand, it might sound like an XY problem, but I'm just asking how do I get that info, and if it's not possible to get it, there's no problem with an answer that might say that there's no such info for ES modules.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer The `parentModuleURL` is given to the *loader* which uses it to resolve relative module specifiers, it is not available inside the module itself. Notice the hook gets invoked for every dependency that is getting imported, even if multiple imports resolve to the same module.

Comment: @Bergi I know that. I wanted to mention this detail so others can be aware of it. I believe the best answer to my question is "there's no way to automatically get this info in ES modules".

Comment: Yeah but as you described it, it makes no sense: _why_ do you need to do this? What bizar system are you using where, if both are your code, and your A needs to know who loaded it (and in which order), why can you not just make that part of A's proper set of calls? E.g. `var A = require('A'); A.addDependents(this);` and done? What are you trying to do where having this baked in makes sense? (because I _cannot_ think of a use case, and would like to know one)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sometimes there're corner cases :D I've implemented a custom ES loader hook and a wrapped of dynamic `import` so I can mock module dependencies. I require, for some specific reason, that info. Anyway, I've been able to get the required info anyway (without `parentModuleUrl` accessible from a module). I just wanted to see if there was a way to get `parentModuleUrl`. If there's no one, as I've already said, an answer that just points out that it's not possible will be the accepted one.

Comment: See, that's the information you should have put in your post, because a Node.js hook that sits on top of `require` already knows who's trying to load what. There is zero need to consult the required module after the fact. You know SO is not just for you, it's also for all future visitors, so this _was_ an XY question, and while you have an answer, it's not super useful for others who will be in your position in the future and find this question hoping to solve their problem later today, tomorrow, next week, or even a few years from now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Did you check the tags in my question? You're completely wrong: it's about ES modules. What `require`/CJS has to do here? The question might be useful for future visitors *as is*: I just asked if I could get that info, and the answer is *no*. There could be millions of devs trying to solve many different cases and the question and the answer *no* could be still useful to don't try to approach some problems with wrong solutions.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans For example, some days ago I answered this question with this answer that's just *no* as what could be the answer to my current question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965820/is-it-possible-to-scan-and-match-a-pattern-using-regex-in-redis/50965896#50965896 . And that answer is still useful for future readers unless Redis changes `MATCH` param to support regular expressions, so in that case, I'll update to *yes, it's absolutely possible*!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans For me, the summary is don't think all SO questions and answers must be about issues with a lot of context. Is it possible to do A? No, you can't do A. And it might be a workaround or not, and if there's no workaround, *no* is a very valid answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain if there's a direct way of doing what you'd like, but here's a workaround: You can create a wrapper function and pass the name of the file.

```
// moduleA.mjs
import {
  wrapper
} from './moduleB.mjs';
const {
  x
} = wrapper('./moduleB.mjs');


// moduleB.mjs (if you want multiple functions to have access to the name)
const wrapper = (nameOfFile) => {
  const x = () => {
    console.log(nameOfFile);
  };
  const y = () => {
    console.log('some other function:', nameOfFile);
  };
  return {
    x,
    y,
  };
}
export const wrapper;

// other approach, if you only want that one function wrapped
// moduleA.mjs
import {
  wrapper
} from './moduleB.mjs';
const x = wrapper('./moduleB.mjs');
// moduleB.mjs
const wrapper = (nameOfFile) => (
  (inputForX) => {
    console.log(nameOfFile);
  })
export const wrapper;
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Anyway, I already knew I could achieve this manually. It seems like there's no such thing for ES modules (loader hooks provide `parentModuleURL`).

Comment: May you edit your answer so it starts with assuming that there's no such thing but for certain cases the later code snippet could be a possible approach?